# Skipping fields in a record using spark-avro

Tags: apache-spark, avro, spark-avro

Update: spark-avro package was update to support this scenario. https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/releases/tag/v3.1.0

I have an AVRO file that was created by a third party outside my control, which I need to process using spark.
The AVRO schema is a record where one of the fields is a mixed union type:

```
{    
    "name" : "Properties",                              
    "type" : {                                          
    "type" : "map",                                   
    "values" : [ "long", "double", "string", "bytes" ]
}
```

This is unsupported with the [spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) reader:

> In addition to the types listed above, it supports reading of three types of union types:
>   union(int, long)
>   union(float, double)
>   union(something, null), where something is one of the supported Avro types listed above or is one of the supported union types.

Reading about AVRO's schema evolution and resolution, I expect to be able to read the file while skipping the problematic field by specifying a different reader schema that omits this field.
According to [AVRO Schema Resolution docs](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution), it should work:

> if the writer's record contains a field with a name not present in the reader's record, the writer's value for that field is ignored.

So I modified using

```
 val df = sqlContext.read.option("avroSchema", avroSchema).avro(path)
```

Where `avroSchema` is the exact same schema, the writer used, but without the problematic field.

But still I get the same error regarding mixed union types.

Is this scenario of schema evolution supported with AVRO? with avro-spark?
Is there another way to achieve my goal?

---

Update:
I have tested the same scenario (same file actually) with Apache Avro 1.8.1 and it works as expected. Then it must be specifically with `spark-avro`. any ideas?

Comment: Not an answer but it appears that `spark-avro` doesn't adhere to AVRO schema evolution \ resolution rules. see:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/issues/176
https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/DefaultSource.scala#L61

Comment: I posted a bounty but it would great if you post what you know so far as an answer in case nobody comes up with a solution.

Comment: What I found was that it cannot be done using spark-avro. Instead I use avro's standard api. I didn't post as answer because it doesn't solves the original question, but proposes a different solution. Do you think it's beneficial to post the code as answer?

Comment: Negative answer is still an answer and if you have a workaround it may save others some time.

Answer (score 5):

Update: spark-avro package was update to support this scenario. https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/releases/tag/v3.1.0

This does not actually answer my question, rather a different solution for the same problem.

Since currently spark-avro is does not have this functionality (see my comment for the question) - I have instead used avro's [org.apache.avro.mapreduce](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/mapreduce/package-summary.html) and spark's [newAPIHadoopFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#newAPIHadoopFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)). Here is a simple example of that:

```
val path = "..."
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("avro test")
  .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") 
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val avroRdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path,
  classOf[AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]],
  classOf[AvroKey[GenericRecord]],
  classOf[NullWritable])
```

contrarily to spark-avro, the official avro libs supports mixed union types and schema evolution.